# App icon is not shown in android device

Tags: android, libgdx

I have developed a game for android device using LibGDX. When I test the app in actual devices the app get installs properly and the app icon is shown in the apps.

When I tried in a device Redmi from xiaomi, a default green robot icon was shown instead of the app's icon. I have even removed the ic_launcher.png from the drawable* folders, the issue still existed. Could you please explain / assist me to resolve this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tryed to copy your ic_launcher.png to every drawable folder?

Comment: I don't have a Redmi device, so couldn't do a test: 
1.you can add icon.png in other three drawable folders
2.you can try add `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` in launch activity's registration in manifest

Comment: Thanks, But I hope my process is correct

Comment: If it works well on all other device, maybe it's the bug of Redmi's Launcher.

Comment: @iappmaker, try on another launcher. If the issue persists - it's an issue from your side. aif it is gone - the issue is in Redmi launcher.